# snippet for scss files not working properly

Tags: sublimetext3

i am creating a snippet for my sass file.
here is my snippet

```
   <snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[

        @include mobLo
        {

        }
        @include mobileHi
        {

        }

        @include tablet
        {

        }
        @include laptop
        {

        }

        @include desktop
        {
        ${}
        }



        ]]></content>

        <tabTrigger>sres</tabTrigger>
        <scope>scss</scope>
    </snippet>
```

Now i have saved it in packages folder under different folder
like `packages>mySnippets`
But somehow it dosen;t work.
**Is my Scope right**?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The scope should probably be `source.scss`. You can check scope by going to an example file where you would want to use the snippet and hit <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> on Mac and looking in the lower left area.

I just noticed that you also have a `$` in your snippet. As it says [here in the docs under "content"](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html?highlight=snippet), you need to escape all `$` with a slash (`\`). Therefore, it should be like this:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
    @include mobLo
    {

    }
    @include mobileHi
    {

    }

    @include tablet
    {

    }
    @include laptop
    {

    }

    @include desktop
    {
    \${}
    }
    ]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>sres</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.scss</scope>
</snippet>
```

Answer (score 0):

the scope needs to be `source.sass` and you need to number your template parameters:

`${1}` or `${1:placeholder}`